# Apple 1 year warranty - What type of issues are covered for Macbook Pro UK?

Tags: macbook-pro, warranty

I am wondering which types of human error or accidental breakage the Apple Manufacturer one year warranty covers.

I have a Macbook Pro which is in full working order, The problem is the reciept for this is in somebody else's name.

I have been told by the store manager in one Apple Store that in order for me to get a new receipt, the only way he could think of is if my Macbook Pro had a "fault" which resulted in me being issued with a new Macbook Pro (and a new receipt).

What the manager was saying is if I could create the conditions for a problem to occur on the Macbook Pro, he could then issue me a new one with a new receipt.

I told him it sounds idiotic for me to do such a thing to a brand new machine, but at the same time it's the only option I have in this politically correct world.

I need the receipt in my name for third party insurance reasons - I cannot insure the Macbook pro with a receipt in somebody else's name.

Comment: tbh, a 1-year warranty in the UK isn't really worth the paper it's printed on. If you have a manufacturing defect you're covered by statutory law. Apple adds a battery 'early death' to that, but you could claim that under statutory rights anyway.  As @BobRon says, no kind of guarantee will ever cover damage or user error, that's what insurance is for. [This is no reflection on Apple themselves, as they tend to fix things under warranty that most sellers would sneer at & tell you to go away - they're very good.]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm glad you asked about it before hitting your MacBook with a sledgehammer. The 1-year limited warranty only covers damage that was caused by a manufacturer defect. Water and/or physical damage is not covered. No exceptions. The only damage that is covered is if the battery drains super quick or whenever you use it it gets way too hot. Or the software does not work properly and you have tried all remedies possible.

Secondly, the only way to get a new receipt is to purchase a new computer. That's really the only way. I broke my iPhone twice, and no new receipt was ever given.

The only way that is possible is to sell your computer and then buy a new/used MacBook.